# php preg_match two things in one time

Tags: php

hello is it possible to match two things using one preg_match?
for example i have a :

```
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
```

and i want to match url (http://google.com) and text (Google)

is it possible to do something like that? something like :

```
preg_match('/^<a href="(.*?)">(.*?)</a>/', $source, $match)
```

then

```
echo 'Url is : ' . $match[1] . ' , and text is : ' . $match[2];
```

**done now thanks**

*i'll accept answers in some mins

Comment: Hi @John -- there is no need to add things like "fixed" or "resolved" to your question title -- the acceptance of an answer is how the system recognizes resolved questions.

Comment: If you are looking for OR syntax, you can get it from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846552/preg-match-or-operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This request is possible to be achieved.  Simply pass the $matches array into the function call.

```
preg_match('/^<a href="(.*?)">(.*?)</a>/', '<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>', $matches);
```

Then, accessing the text of the matches by relevant numeric index!

```
echo $matches[1]; //"http://google.com"
echo $matches[2]; //"Google"
```

Answer (score 2):

yes of course

```
  preg_match('/^<a href="(?<url>.*?)">(?<anchor>.*?)</a>/',$yourtext,$matches);

  echo 'Url is : ' . $matches['url'] . ' , and text is : ' . $matches['anchor'] ;
```

Comment: thanks for the '(?<url>.*?)' i didn't know about that :D it will help me much, in the future.

Answer (score 2):

This is a where named subpatterns come in

example taken directly from [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
<?php

$str = 'foobar: 2008';

preg_match('/(?P<name>\w+): (?P<digit>\d+)/', $str, $matches);

/* This also works in PHP 5.2.2 (PCRE 7.0) and later, however 
 * the above form is recommended for backwards compatibility */
// preg_match('/(?<name>\w+): (?<digit>\d+)/', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);

?>
```

results in

```
Array
(
    [0] => foobar: 2008
    [name] => foobar
    [1] => foobar
    [digit] => 2008
    [2] => 2008
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible -- just pass a third parameter to [**`preg_match()`**](https://www.php.net/preg_match) :

```
$str = '<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>';
if (preg_match('#<a href="(.*?)">(.*?)</a>#', $str, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

And here's the `$matches` array :

```
array
  0 => string '<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>' (length=38)
  1 => string 'http://google.com' (length=17)
  2 => string 'Google' (length=6)
```

The first match is in `$matches[1]`, and the second one in `$matches[2]`.

Note : not sure what you are exactly trying to do... But just in case : Regular Expressions are very usable for simple extractions, but they cannot cope with syntactic HTML variations without significant more effort.

Instead, especially for more complex situations than this one, or when speed doesn't matter (input instead of output processing), you might want to use an XML parser.

For example, in PHP, you could use [**`DOMDocument::loadHTML()`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php).

Comment: To the one who downvoted : could you please explain what is wrong in my answer ? That would help everyone avoiding a possible mistake :-)

Comment: I've downvoted. And I'm not ashamed to admit my rudeness. I'm objecting to the `regular expressions are not the right tool bla bla`. It's a perfectly cromulent tool for extracting shit. Firing up a DOM parser to extract letters from on a few dozen html snippets is not a good idea. So without knowing the use case, it's a useless meme recommendation. And it contradicts the quality of the first half of your answer.

Comment: OK ; thanks for the comment and your explanation :-) *(You don't need to feel ashamed or anything : I just wanted to know if there was something wrong with my answer, and what :-) )*

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
preg_match("/^<a href=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)</a>/", $string, $matches);
```

$matches will contain the matched patterns in an array.