# preg_match or operator

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

My code below produces an error, unknown modified "|"... I'm trying to use it as the OR operator. What is the correct way to run this code without error?

```
$p = "(\w+)|(\()|(\))|(\,)";
$s =  "sum(blue,paper,green(yellow,4,toast)))";
preg_match($p,$s, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

### Edit

Okay I changed it a bit... `~(\w+|\(|\)|,)~`

Now... here's the problem: I need to take that string and split it into an array like this:

`array("sum","(","blue","paper","green","(" ... etc );`

Can someone help me do that? when I run the above expression it outputs an empty array....

Thanks

Comment: `$p = '~(\w+)|([(])|([)])|(,)~';` would be more readable IMO, and you don't need to escape the comma.

Comment: re: edit - I get an output of [0] => sum [1] => sum.  Works fine, except for 2 things: 1) your expected array doesn't show the commas as array elements, so you need to remove that from your pattern if you don't want it.  2) You should be using preg_match_all if you want more than one match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the delimiter as @Crayon correctly mentioned, also this pattern does the same thing:

```
$p = '~(\w+|[(]|[)]|,)~';
```

---

As for your (new) problem, [try this](http://ideone.com/46haq):

```
$p = '~([(),])~';
$str = 'sum(blue,paper,green(yellow,4,toast)))';
$res = preg_split($p, $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

print_r($res);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => sum
    [1] => (
    [2] => blue
    [3] => ,
    [4] => paper
    [5] => ,
    [6] => green
    [7] => (
    [8] => yellow
    [9] => ,
    [10] => 4
    [11] => ,
    [12] => toast
    [13] => )
    [14] => )
    [15] => )
)
```

Comment: Split is correct as long as the OP doesn't have any other characters - for `1+2`, for example, split returns `"1","+","2"`, but the OP's code returns ``"1","2"``, ignoring other characters (even spaces are ignored, though the sample string has no such characters). Also, `~([(),])~` is neater looking `:)`

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the delimiter for your pattern.

`$p = "~(\w+)|(\()|(\))|(\,)~";`

Comment: honestly I don't know why people use anything else :)

Comment: +1 It works but it still doesn't do what I want. Can you help me out?